# Where I can find actual android build tool version that used if it uspecified

Tags: android, android-studio, build-tools

> If you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, your project automatically uses a default version of the build tools that the plugin specifies.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools

How can I check what build tools version is actual used if I have no buildToolsVersion in my build.gradle and no  ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project Structure then select Module.[image: As shown in image]

Comment: At least on Android Studio 3.5.3, that field shows up blank for a module that does not specify `buildToolsVersion`.

Comment: this filed is blank because >I have no buildToolsVersion in my build.gradle

Comment: If you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, your project automatically uses a default version of the build tools that the plugin specifies. See here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools